# Create React App is Deployed but github pages shows 404 from manifest.json

Tags: create-react-app

Can anyone help me identify the problem to my manifest json file?

I deployed a simple starter create-react app to github pages and through the command line it shows that is is published but when I go to github pages page doesnt load. When I view the console I get this 404 error message coming from the manifest.json file , and static css file

[image]

I've searched everywhere for answers but I cant find a solution , if anyone could help that would be great

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not as a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The last error message in the console shows:

```
Manifest: line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

Note that line 1, column 1 of your code is an angle bracket: `<`

That angle bracket is the "Unexpected token". JSON files are expected to begin with `{` not `<` which is appropriate for XML or HTML files.

Manifest.json is a JSON file which, according to the Mozilla article below, should be "formatted as JSON, with the possible exception of `"//"` comments."

Below I have included a very short example of a manifest.json file. A longer example with further information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "awesome app",
  "name": "Awesome App",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Another example of the JSON format is shown here: https://json.org/example.html