# My link to manifest.json in index.html works when I run react script 'yarn start', but not when I run 'python3 manage.py runserver'

Tags: html, json, python-3.x, reactjs, django-staticfiles

When I run 'yarn start', my link to manifest.json in my index.html file works fine, but when I run `'python3 manage.py runserver'` all I get in the terminal is:

```
Not Found: /manifest.json
"GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2234
```

This also happens to all of my static links and imports. I'm pretty new to Django and React, and programming as a whole, so I think that I'm just missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

I've been trying to use `{% load static %}`, but the link doesn't work, even if I edit `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py` to point towards my `manifest.json` directory. I also attempted to edit `view.py` and `urls.py`, but all I get is syntax errors in the terminal. Other than that I'm clueless.

frontend/public/index.html

```html
<html>

    <head>

    <title>WebProject</title>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>

    </head>

    <body style="background-color: #FAF0E6; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40px;">
    <div id="root"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

frontend/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),

]
```

frontend/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/public/index.html')
```

I expected my browser to load manifest.json properly, along with any other links or imports, but I keep getting a blank page.

Im using React inside of Django, so when I tried to import my `index.js` the same "Not Found" terminal error popped up. Im assuming that if I solve the `manifest.json` problem, I'll also solve my other import and link problems.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found this [Can't get rid of missing manifest.json error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527972/cant-get-rid-of-missing-manifest-json-error)

Well, in my case it was browser cache related and swapping to incognito mode was enough.

Comment: i confirm, the error disappears in incognito mode

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me (blank page and unable to load `manifest.json` + react build's static files) and I solved the issues thanks to this excellent [article](https://www.techiediaries.com/create-react-app-django/)

Solution -> assuming your react app (`build` etc.) are in a folder called `frontend` at the same level as your django project, in your `settings.py` file you need to make sure your `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable is set like below (don't forget the trailing coma as it is a tuple).

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend'), 'build', 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Nit: I don't think you need to nest two os.paht.join, i.e., `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'build', 'static')` should work as the same.

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py:

from django.urls import re_path

CHANGE:
urlpatterns = [
...
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')]

TO:

urlpatterns = [
...
re_path('.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')]

Had the same error and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to wrap the App with BrowserRouter in an Index.js file

```js
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```