# GET http://localhost:8000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found) ERROR in Django with React

Tags: reactjs, django, manifest.json

I am currently learning React.js and started to combine it with Django.

I tried to build a simple homepage that will display *Hello, World!*

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

It works fine on the browser, but when I check the console, there is an error `GET http://localhost:8000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)`. What is this `manifest.json` file that I am missing?

This is how I set up my Django project settings:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static')]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build')],
            ...
            ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My project tree looks like this:

[image]

And the error looks like this:

[image]

What can I do with this error?

Comment: In your static directory I see manifest.json file. What is it that you are doing with it ?

Comment: It is already there when I created my react app. I didnt put it there. And I didnt do or write anything in there. I just followed react documentations on how to start a react app. @rootkonda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253325/my-link-to-manifest-json-in-index-html-works-when-i-run-react-script-yarn-start

Comment: I tried removing link to manifest.js in index.html and tried to run python manage.py runserver and looked at the console, the error isnt there. however, in order to see changes you made on react app, I need to run ```npm run build``` on cmd and it recreates the manifest.json file. Should I leave it be?

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file in the main folder of your React project and write the next line {--> "homepage": "./", <--} without the "{" and arrows. This worked for me in [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```py
path('manifest.json', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='manifest.json', content_type='application/json'), name='manifest.json')
```

in your urls.py file

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htxC3.png)